# ¿Cómo evito que mi sesión PHP expire?

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo un problema con la vida de sesión en PHP, desarrolle mi aplicación web con logueo con roles (login.php), todo funciona bien esa parte los usuarios acceden correctamente (home.php), mi problema es que después de cierto tiempo si lleno algún formulario con request a un script PHP no se completa o si tan simplemente hago "*refresh*" a la página me manda a que me logue de nuevo porque la $_SESSION deja de "vivir".

Les comparto un poco de mi código, para que puedan revisarlo, cabe mencionar que tengo AJAX en mi aplicación web:

Método done, recibe un JSON con el tipo de rol

```
}).done( (response) => {
    if (response.estado) {
        // Redirigir al usuario a su pagina por rol despues de 5 segundos
        setTimeout( () => {
            if (response.tipoRol === 2) {
                location.href = 'agente.php';
            } else if (response.tipoRol === 1) {
                location.href = 'supervisor.php';
            }
        }, 5000);
        return;
    }
    // Habilita campos credenciales de acceso, boton iniciar session, checkbox contrasenia
    $('#boton_login, #contrasenia_pb, #switch_login, #usuario_pb').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

Script PHP de login, es lo clásico, es decir una consulta a la base de datos en la tabla de usuarios, valida las credenciales y otorga el acceso, este manda el JSON como response a la petición AJAX, de aquí en adelante pues manda la pantalla correspondiente.

**PANTALLA LOGIN:** En esta pantalla coloco el siguiente script PHP al inicio, lo demás en adelante es el maquetado y CSS

```
// Includes y Requires
require('../includes/configuraciones.php');
// Autorizacion de acceso por tipo de rol
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_ws'])) {
    switch ($_SESSION['usuario_ws']['id_cargo']) {
        case 1: // Pantalla Supervisor
            header('location:supervisor.php');
        break;
        case 2: // Pantalla Agente
            header('location:agente.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

**PANTALLA AGENTE:** En esta pantalla coloco el siguiente script PHP al inicio, lo demás en adelante es el maquetado y CSS

```
// Includes y Requires    
require('../includes/configuraciones.php');
// Autorizacion de acceso por tipo de rol
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_ws'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['usuario_ws']['id_cargo'] != 2) {
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location:../index.php');
}
require('../includes/header.php');
```

Como podrán ver tengo un archivo configuraciones.php, ¿Qué tengo en ese archivo?

```
// Header Request
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
// Tiempo de vida de variable de session
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '7200');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '7200');
// Configuracion fecha PHP
date_default_timezone_set('America/Monterrey');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
// Iniciar una nueva session o reanudar la existente
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

En lo que pueden ver tengo los "ini_set", estos porqué estuve investigando y según esos métodos con 7200 me da 2 horas de vida en la $_SESSION, pero no me funciona, también tengo el código de la condicional if según aplica que si la $_SESSION esta "muerta" la "revive".

Estuve investigando esos datos del párrafo anterior, según son la mejor opción junto con modificar el archivo .htaccess o el php.ini, siendo franco no le entendí mucho.

También observe tutoriales en YouTube, encontre unos sobre revisar un dato en DevTools, les dejo la imagen de la parte que tenía que revisar:

[image: Pestaña "Aplication" en Devtools]

La verdad ya me di un buen clavado en Internet pero nada más no doy con la solución, cabe mencionar que estoy programando con PHP puro, sin ningún framework, ¿Cuál es mi problema?, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¿Ocupan que modifique la pregunta para añadir más información?